# CSS transition does not work when clicking button

Tags: css, transition

I want a button to trigger a popup. The pop shows when the button is clicked but it happens really abruptly so I want to add a transition but it doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<button class="terug"></button>
```

CSS:

```
img.popup{
    width: 15em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25em;
    left: 4em;
    transition: ease-in 1s;
  }
```

JS:

```
var uno =       document.querySelector('button.terug');

var popup = document.querySelector('img.popup');

uno.addEventListener ('click', function(){
    popup.classList.toggle('popup');
});
```

Comment: There is no element `img.popup` in your HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by `add a transition to a popup`?

Comment: @YaakovAinspanI forgot to include it here but it is in my html

Comment: I want an image that acts as a popup to ease into the screen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

```
    var popup = document.querySelector('img');
```

Instead of :

```
    var popup = document.querySelector('img.popup');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an way you could do it using pure JavaScript. Although I would recommend you use a third library or a Jquery plugin.

```js
const openPopup = () => {
  const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  popup.classList.add("opened");
}
```

```css
.image-popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 200px);
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-popup.opened {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openPopup()">Open image</button>
<div id="popup" class="image-popup">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/any">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I'd definitely say that if you can avoid including a library just for one thing, is better to do so. Remember that including jQuery and other plugins can affect you page's loading, so, the fewer requests, the better

Comment: I totally agree with you, @IvanS95. My advice is meant to be for a project that already loads jQuery for another purpose.